# GET request to the Google calendar API

Tags: javascript, jquery, get, google-api

Is it possible to make a GET request to the Google calendar API?

I am using AngularJS to create GET request. But it is not important for me how I will send a GET request(with jQuery, Angular etc.). I am interesting in response.

```
test.controller('TestCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.title="I WANT TO MAKE A REQUEST";
    $http.get('https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/'{{calendarid}}'/events?key='{{apiKey}}').success(function(data){
        $scope.tests= data;
    });
```

[here is a screenshot](http://take.ms/Jk9qe) of my variables **calendarid** and **apiKey** values

Maybe I am doing something wrong? Or you can suggest something? Any answer will be appreciated!

P.S. Please say if you need more details.

Answer (score 0):

Since you a user's calendar, you will need to authenticate with either an OAuth Client or a service account (i.e. a robot user) rather than an API key. The OAuth Client ID that you pointed out is different from the calendar ID. The easiest way to find the calendar ID is to [make a calendar list call](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/list#try-it).

I recommend checking out [this getting started](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/js) guide on how to use the Google API JavaScript library to look up calendar data.